# SQL - count rows with same value

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, count, phpmyadmin

I would like to group and list all the rows that have the same value (gruppo_muscolare.nome) and count how many values (esercizio.nome) are related to the same value, but if I use GROUP BY then I only get the single results without the full list.

```
SELECT
gruppo_muscolare.nome,
esercizio.nome,
COUNT(gruppo_muscolare.nome) AS counter
FROM tabella_allenamento, scheda, esercizio_scheda, esercizio, gruppo_muscolare
WHERE tabella_allenamento.id = 29 AND scheda.id_tabella=tabella_allenamento.id
AND esercizio_scheda.id_scheda=scheda.id AND esercizio.id=esercizio_scheda.id_esercizio
AND gruppo_muscolare.id=esercizio.id_gruppo_muscolare
GROUP BY gruppo_muscolare.nome, esercizio.nome, 
gruppo_muscolare.id 
ORDER BY counter DESC
```

I get:

```
nome                  nome                 counter 
pettorali          Chest Press               1
pettorali      incline press hammer          1
quadricipiti       Leg Curl                  1
```

while I would like to get:

```
nome                  nome                 counter 
pettorali          Chest Press               2
pettorali      incline press hammer          2
quadricipiti       Leg Curl                  1
```

If I use the GROUP BY statement with only a value:

```
SELECT gruppo_muscolare.nome,
esercizio.nome, 
COUNT(gruppo_muscolare.nome) AS counter 
FROM tabella_allenamento, scheda, esercizio_scheda, esercizio, gruppo_muscolare
WHERE tabella_allenamento.id = 29 AND scheda.id_tabella=tabella_allenamento.id
AND esercizio_scheda.id_scheda=scheda.id AND esercizio.id=esercizio_scheda.id_esercizio
AND gruppo_muscolare.id=esercizio.id_gruppo_muscolare
GROUP BY gruppo_muscolare.nome
ORDER BY counter DESC
```

then I get:

```
nome                  nome                 counter 
pettorali          Chest Press               2
quadricipiti       Leg Curl                  1
```

that it's what I want but a result is missing.

How can I list ALL the results and at the same time also get the correct counter that counts how many `esercizio.nome` there are for each `gruppo_muscolare.nome`?

Thank you!

**EDIT**: This is the SQL to create and populate all the tables in order to be able to run and test the code.

```
    -- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 5.0.1
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Creato il: Mar 07, 2021 alle 13:00
-- Versione del server: 10.4.11-MariaDB
-- Versione PHP: 7.4.2

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Database: `pump_db`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Struttura della tabella `esercizio`
--

CREATE TABLE `esercizio` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nome` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `id_gruppo_muscolare` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `gruppo_muscolare` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Dump dei dati per la tabella `esercizio`
--

INSERT INTO `esercizio` (`id`, `nome`, `id_gruppo_muscolare`, `gruppo_muscolare`) VALUES
(1, 'incline press hammer', 1, 'pettorali'),
(2, 'Chest Press ', 1, 'pettorali'),
(3, 'Leg Curl', 2, 'quadricipiti'),
(4, 'spinte con manubri', 3, 'spalle'),
(5, 'Lat machine', 5, 'dorsali'),
(8, 'spalle', 3, 'incline press hammer'),
(10, 'Pulley con triangolo', 5, 'dorsali'),
(11, 'croci su panca piana', 1, 'pettorali');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Struttura della tabella `esercizio_scheda`
--

CREATE TABLE `esercizio_scheda` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_esercizio` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_scheda` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `serie` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `ripetizioni` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `kg` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `note` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Dump dei dati per la tabella `esercizio_scheda`
--

INSERT INTO `esercizio_scheda` (`id`, `id_esercizio`, `id_scheda`, `serie`, `ripetizioni`, `kg`, `note`) VALUES
(38, 2, 26, '3', '2', '', ''),
(39, 1, 26, '1', '2', '', ''),
(40, 3, 26, '2', '3', '', ''),
(41, 11, 27, '2', '10-2-1', '', ''),
(42, 2, 27, '3', '2', '', ''),
(43, 1, 27, '1', '2', '', '');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Struttura della tabella `gruppo_muscolare`
--

CREATE TABLE `gruppo_muscolare` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nome` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Dump dei dati per la tabella `gruppo_muscolare`
--

INSERT INTO `gruppo_muscolare` (`id`, `nome`) VALUES
(1, 'pettorali'),
(2, 'quadricipiti'),
(3, 'spalle'),
(4, 'glutei'),
(5, 'dorsali'),
(6, 'bicipiti'),
(7, 'tricipiti'),
(8, 'adduttori'),
(9, 'abduttori'),
(10, 'addominali'),
(11, 'femorali');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Struttura della tabella `personal_trainer`
--

CREATE TABLE `personal_trainer` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nome` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `cognome` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `codice_pt` int(50) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Dump dei dati per la tabella `personal_trainer`
--

INSERT INTO `personal_trainer` (`id`, `nome`, `cognome`, `codice_pt`, `email`) VALUES
(1, 'Jacopo', 'Stefano', 1, ''),
(2, 'Federica', 'Metto', 2, ''),
(3, 'Paolo', 'Marsella', 33, '');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Struttura della tabella `scheda`
--

CREATE TABLE `scheda` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_tabella` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tipo` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `data` date NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp()
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Dump dei dati per la tabella `scheda`
--

INSERT INTO `scheda` (`id`, `id_tabella`, `tipo`, `data`) VALUES
(26, 29, 'A', '2021-02-28'),
(27, 30, 'A', '2021-02-28');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Struttura della tabella `tabella_allenamento`
--

CREATE TABLE `tabella_allenamento` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_utente` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nome` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `pt` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `data` date NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `data_inizio` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `data_fine` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `recupero_serie` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `recupero_esercizio` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Dump dei dati per la tabella `tabella_allenamento`
--

INSERT INTO `tabella_allenamento` (`id`, `id_utente`, `nome`, `pt`, `data`, `data_inizio`, `data_fine`, `recupero_serie`, `recupero_esercizio`) VALUES
(29, 1000, 'Rocco Galati #1000-2021-02-28-11-38-07', 'Jacopo Stefano', '2021-02-28', '28-02-2021', '30-03-2021', '1:30\"', '1:30\"'),
(30, 1000, 'Rocco Galati #1000-2021-02-28-11-39-16', 'Jacopo Stefano', '2021-02-28', '28-02-2021', '30-03-2021', '1:30\"', '1:30\"');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Struttura della tabella `utente`
--

CREATE TABLE `utente` (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `nome` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `cognome` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `cf` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `peso` float NOT NULL,
  `altezza` float NOT NULL,
  `note` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `data_di_nascita` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `telefono` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Dump dei dati per la tabella `utente`
--

INSERT INTO `utente` (`id`, `nome`, `cognome`, `cf`, `peso`, `altezza`, `note`, `email`, `data_di_nascita`, `telefono`) VALUES
(1000, 'Rocco', 'Galati', 'GLTRCC84R04E825L', 80, 178, 'Nessuna nota', 'roccogalati@gmail.com', '04/10/1984', '3280613637'),
(1002, 'Marco', 'Rossi', 'GLTRCC85R04E815L', 90, 180, 'nessuna nota particolare', 'info@robo-dyne.com', '04/10/1985', '3280613637');

--
-- Indici per le tabelle scaricate
--

--
-- Indici per le tabelle `esercizio`
--
ALTER TABLE `esercizio`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Indici per le tabelle `esercizio_scheda`
--
ALTER TABLE `esercizio_scheda`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Indici per le tabelle `gruppo_muscolare`
--
ALTER TABLE `gruppo_muscolare`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Indici per le tabelle `personal_trainer`
--
ALTER TABLE `personal_trainer`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Indici per le tabelle `scheda`
--
ALTER TABLE `scheda`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Indici per le tabelle `tabella_allenamento`
--
ALTER TABLE `tabella_allenamento`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Indici per le tabelle `utente`
--
ALTER TABLE `utente`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT per le tabelle scaricate
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT per la tabella `esercizio`
--
ALTER TABLE `esercizio`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=16;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT per la tabella `esercizio_scheda`
--
ALTER TABLE `esercizio_scheda`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=44;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT per la tabella `gruppo_muscolare`
--
ALTER TABLE `gruppo_muscolare`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=15;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT per la tabella `personal_trainer`
--
ALTER TABLE `personal_trainer`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=4;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT per la tabella `scheda`
--
ALTER TABLE `scheda`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=28;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT per la tabella `tabella_allenamento`
--
ALTER TABLE `tabella_allenamento`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=31;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT per la tabella `utente`
--
ALTER TABLE `utente`
  MODIFY `id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=1007;
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: please provide a [mre] for the result you get

Comment: sorry, I forgot to include it! I just edited my first post by adding the whole SQL to create and populate all the tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a `GROUP BY` clause, use the `COUNT()` function as a [**window function**](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/) so you get all rows back like so:

```
SELECT
gruppo_muscolare.nome,
esercizio.nome,
COUNT(esercizio.nome) OVER (PARTITION BY 
gruppo_muscolare.nome) AS counter
FROM tabella_allenamento, scheda, esercizio_scheda, esercizio, 
gruppo_muscolare
WHERE tabella_allenamento.id = 29 AND 
scheda.id_tabella=tabella_allenamento.id
AND esercizio_scheda.id_scheda=scheda.id AND 
esercizio.id=esercizio_scheda.id_esercizio
AND gruppo_muscolare.id=esercizio.id_gruppo_muscolare
ORDER BY counter DESC
```

Comment: It worked like a charm! Thank you for the solution, it's really smart! I never heard about the OVER clause!

Comment: @MarcusBarnet Great, no problem! Yea **window functions** (the `OVER` clause) are super useful. I highly recommend reading up on the link I provided about them. Another really awesome one is `ROW_NUMBER()` which allows you to enumerate your rows within a `PARTITION` (grouping) so you can `SELECT` things like the first or last N number of rows within that grouping (e.g. if you ordered by a date or identity field).

Comment: Thank you a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

i can't understand how you will get to that numbers.
As you can see tabella_allenamento  29 has only 3 exercises and only one Chest Press in it, so you must have other data in mind when you wrote the query.

The last table shows  the the cummulated tables with all data, so you can see what your single tables yield for a result when they a properly joined.

For the future use `JOIN` instead of commas in tables, they are aroud for 20 years, also aliases help to keep the query readable

So chekc your table and see if you misst some rows for tabella_allenamento   29

> ```
> CREATE TABLE `esercizio` (
>   `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
>   `nome` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
>   `id_gruppo_muscolare` int(11) NOT NULL,
>   `gruppo_muscolare` varchar(50) NOT NULL
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
>
> --
> -- Dump dei dati per la tabella `esercizio`
> --
>
> INSERT INTO `esercizio` (`id`, `nome`, `id_gruppo_muscolare`, `gruppo_muscolare`) VALUES
> (1, 'incline press hammer', 1, 'pettorali'),
> (2, 'Chest Press ', 1, 'pettorali'),
> (3, 'Leg Curl', 2, 'quadricipiti'),
> (4, 'spinte con manubri', 3, 'spalle'),
> (5, 'Lat machine', 5, 'dorsali'),
> (8, 'spalle', 3, 'incline press hammer'),
> (10, 'Pulley con triangolo', 5, 'dorsali'),
> (11, 'croci su panca piana', 1, 'pettorali');
>
> -- --------------------------------------------------------
>
> --
> -- Struttura della tabella `esercizio_scheda`
> --
>
> CREATE TABLE `esercizio_scheda` (
>   `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
>   `id_esercizio` int(11) NOT NULL,
>   `id_scheda` int(11) NOT NULL,
>   `serie` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
>   `ripetizioni` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
>   `kg` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
>   `note` varchar(100) NOT NULL
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
>
> --
> -- Dump dei dati per la tabella `esercizio_scheda`
> --
>
> INSERT INTO `esercizio_scheda` (`id`, `id_esercizio`, `id_scheda`, `serie`, `ripetizioni`, `kg`, `note`) VALUES
> (38, 2, 26, '3', '2', '', ''),
> (39, 1, 26, '1', '2', '', ''),
> (40, 3, 26, '2', '3', '', ''),
> (41, 11, 27, '2', '10-2-1', '', ''),
> (42, 2, 27, '3', '2', '', ''),
> (43, 1, 27, '1', '2', '', '');
>
> -- --------------------------------------------------------
>
> --
> -- Struttura della tabella `gruppo_muscolare`
> --
>
> CREATE TABLE `gruppo_muscolare` (
>   `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
>   `nome` varchar(100) NOT NULL
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
>
> --
> -- Dump dei dati per la tabella `gruppo_muscolare`
> --
>
> INSERT INTO `gruppo_muscolare` (`id`, `nome`) VALUES
> (1, 'pettorali'),
> (2, 'quadricipiti'),
> (3, 'spalle'),
> (4, 'glutei'),
> (5, 'dorsali'),
> (6, 'bicipiti'),
> (7, 'tricipiti'),
> (8, 'adduttori'),
> (9, 'abduttori'),
> (10, 'addominali'),
> (11, 'femorali');
>
> -- --------------------------------------------------------
>
> --
> -- Struttura della tabella `personal_trainer`
> --
>
> CREATE TABLE `personal_trainer` (
>   `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
>   `nome` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
>   `cognome` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
>   `codice_pt` int(50) NOT NULL,
>   `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
>
> --
> -- Dump dei dati per la tabella `personal_trainer`
> --
>
> INSERT INTO `personal_trainer` (`id`, `nome`, `cognome`, `codice_pt`, `email`) VALUES
> (1, 'Jacopo', 'Stefano', 1, ''),
> (2, 'Federica', 'Metto', 2, ''),
> (3, 'Paolo', 'Marsella', 33, '');
>
> -- --------------------------------------------------------
>
> --
> -- Struttura della tabella `scheda`
> --
>
> CREATE TABLE `scheda` (
>   `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
>   `id_tabella` int(11) NOT NULL,
>   `tipo` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
>   `data` date NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp()
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
>
> --
> -- Dump dei dati per la tabella `scheda`
> --
>
> INSERT INTO `scheda` (`id`, `id_tabella`, `tipo`, `data`) VALUES
> (26, 29, 'A', '2021-02-28'),
> (27, 30, 'A', '2021-02-28');
>
> -- --------------------------------------------------------
>
> --
> -- Struttura della tabella `tabella_allenamento`
> --
>
> CREATE TABLE `tabella_allenamento` (
>   `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
>   `id_utente` int(11) NOT NULL,
>   `nome` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
>   `pt` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
>   `data` date NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
>   `data_inizio` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
>   `data_fine` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
>   `recupero_serie` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
>   `recupero_esercizio` varchar(100) NOT NULL
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
>
> --
> -- Dump dei dati per la tabella `tabella_allenamento`
> --
>
> INSERT INTO `tabella_allenamento` (`id`, `id_utente`, `nome`, `pt`, `data`, `data_inizio`, `data_fine`, `recupero_serie`, `recupero_esercizio`) VALUES
> (29, 1000, 'Rocco Galati #1000-2021-02-28-11-38-07', 'Jacopo Stefano', '2021-02-28', '28-02-2021', '30-03-2021', '1:30\"', '1:30\"'),
> (30, 1000, 'Rocco Galati #1000-2021-02-28-11-39-16', 'Jacopo Stefano', '2021-02-28', '28-02-2021', '30-03-2021', '1:30\"', '1:30\"');
>
> -- --------------------------------------------------------
>
> --
> -- Struttura della tabella `utente`
> --
>
> CREATE TABLE `utente` (
>   `id` int(255) NOT NULL,
>   `nome` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
>   `cognome` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
>   `cf` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
>   `peso` float NOT NULL,
>   `altezza` float NOT NULL,
>   `note` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
>   `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
>   `data_di_nascita` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
>   `telefono` varchar(50) NOT NULL
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
>
> --
> -- Dump dei dati per la tabella `utente`
> --
>
> INSERT INTO `utente` (`id`, `nome`, `cognome`, `cf`, `peso`, `altezza`, `note`, `email`, `data_di_nascita`, `telefono`) VALUES
> (1000, 'Rocco', 'Galati', 'GLTRCC84R04E825L', 80, 178, 'Nessuna nota', 'roccogalati@gmail.com', '04/10/1984', '3280613637'),
> (1002, 'Marco', 'Rossi', 'GLTRCC85R04E815L', 90, 180, 'nessuna nota particolare', 'info@robo-dyne.com', '04/10/1985', '3280613637');
>
> --
> -- Indici per le tabelle scaricate
> --
>
> --
> -- Indici per le tabelle `esercizio`
> --
> ALTER TABLE `esercizio`
>   ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
>
> --
> -- Indici per le tabelle `esercizio_scheda`
> --
> ALTER TABLE `esercizio_scheda`
>   ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
>
> --
> -- Indici per le tabelle `gruppo_muscolare`
> --
> ALTER TABLE `gruppo_muscolare`
>   ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
>
> --
> -- Indici per le tabelle `personal_trainer`
> --
> ALTER TABLE `personal_trainer`
>   ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
>
> --
> -- Indici per le tabelle `scheda`
> --
> ALTER TABLE `scheda`
>   ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
>
> --
> -- Indici per le tabelle `tabella_allenamento`
> --
> ALTER TABLE `tabella_allenamento`
>   ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
>
> --
> -- Indici per le tabelle `utente`
> --
> ALTER TABLE `utente`
>   ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
>
> --
> -- AUTO_INCREMENT per le tabelle scaricate
> --
>
> --
> -- AUTO_INCREMENT per la tabella `esercizio`
> --
> ALTER TABLE `esercizio`
>   MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=16;
>
> --
> -- AUTO_INCREMENT per la tabella `esercizio_scheda`
> --
> ALTER TABLE `esercizio_scheda`
>   MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=44;
>
> --
> -- AUTO_INCREMENT per la tabella `gruppo_muscolare`
> --
> ALTER TABLE `gruppo_muscolare`
>   MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=15;
>
> --
> -- AUTO_INCREMENT per la tabella `personal_trainer`
> --
> ALTER TABLE `personal_trainer`
>   MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=4;
>
> --
> -- AUTO_INCREMENT per la tabella `scheda`
> --
> ALTER TABLE `scheda`
>   MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=28;
>
> --
> -- AUTO_INCREMENT per la tabella `tabella_allenamento`
> --
> ALTER TABLE `tabella_allenamento`
>   MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=31;
>
> --
> -- AUTO_INCREMENT per la tabella `utente`
> --
> ALTER TABLE `utente`
>   MODIFY `id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=1007;
> COMMIT;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
> gm.nome,
> e.nome
> ,COUNT(gm.nome) AS counter
> FROM tabella_allenamento ta
> LEFT JOIN scheda s ON s.id_tabella=ta.id
> LEFT JOIN  esercizio_scheda es ON es.id_scheda=s.id
> LEFT JOIN esercizio e ON e.id=es.id_esercizio
> LEFT JOIN gruppo_muscolare gm ON gm.id=e.id_gruppo_muscolare
> WHERE ta.id = 29 OR ta.id = 30
> GROUP BY gm.nome, e.nome, gm.id 
> ORDER BY counter DESC
> ```

> ```
> nome         | nome                 | counter
> :----------- | :------------------- | ------:
> pettorali    | Chest Press          |       2
> pettorali    | incline press hammer |       2
> quadricipiti | Leg Curl             |       1
> pettorali    | croci su panca piana |       1
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
> s.*
> ,es.*
> ,e.*
> , gm.*
> FROM scheda s
> INNER JOIN esercizio_scheda es ON es.id_scheda=s.id
> INNER JOIN esercizio e ON e.id=es.id_esercizio 
> INNER JOIn gruppo_muscolare gm ON gm.id=e.id_gruppo_muscolare
> ```
>
> ```
> id | id_tabella | tipo | data       | id | id_esercizio | id_scheda | serie | ripetizioni | kg | note | id | nome                 | id_gruppo_muscolare | gruppo_muscolare | id | nome        
> -: | ---------: | :--- | :--------- | -: | -----------: | --------: | :---- | :---------- | :- | :--- | -: | :------------------- | ------------------: | :--------------- | -: | :-----------
> 26 |         29 | A    | 2021-02-28 | 38 |            2 |        26 | 3     | 2           |    |      |  2 | Chest Press          |                   1 | pettorali        |  1 | pettorali   
> 26 |         29 | A    | 2021-02-28 | 39 |            1 |        26 | 1     | 2           |    |      |  1 | incline press hammer |                   1 | pettorali        |  1 | pettorali   
> 26 |         29 | A    | 2021-02-28 | 40 |            3 |        26 | 2     | 3           |    |      |  3 | Leg Curl             |                   2 | quadricipiti     |  2 | quadricipiti
> 27 |         30 | A    | 2021-02-28 | 41 |           11 |        27 | 2     | 10-2-1      |    |      | 11 | croci su panca piana |                   1 | pettorali        |  1 | pettorali   
> 27 |         30 | A    | 2021-02-28 | 42 |            2 |        27 | 3     | 2           |    |      |  2 | Chest Press          |                   1 | pettorali        |  1 | pettorali   
> 27 |         30 | A    | 2021-02-28 | 43 |            1 |        27 | 1     | 2           |    |      |  1 | incline press hammer |                   1 | pettorali        |  1 | pettorali
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=3dd55f5c5626616e505300beb5a2e458)*